# How to do a cascade SelectList in .Net Core 2.2 Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

We have these 3 SelectLists (dropdown-list) - Roles, Clubs and Hosts. If Roles = "Club Admin" then the Clubs selectlist will appear while Roles = "Host Admin" then Hosts will appear while the Roles none of those, those 2 selectlist will not appear.

Any ideas on how to do this?

**Envronments:**

- .Net Core 2.2

**Create.cshtml:**

```
@page
@model AthlosifyWebArchery.Pages.Administrators.Users.CreateModel
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
<h4>User</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.Email" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.Address" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.Address" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.Address" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.Suburb" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.Suburb" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.Suburb" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.State" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.State" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.State" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.Postcode" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.Postcode" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.Postcode" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.Country" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.Country" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.Country" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.UserName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.UserName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            Role:
            <select asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedRoleId" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="form-control"
                    asp-items="@Model.RoleNameSL">
                <option value="">-- Select Role --</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedRoleId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Club:
                <select asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedClubID" class="form-control"
                        asp-items="@Model.ClubNameSL">
                    <option value="">-- Select Club --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedClubID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Host:
                <select asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedHostID" class="form-control"
                        asp-items="@Model.HostNameSL">
                    <option value="">-- Select Host --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedHostID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div>
   <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
@section Scripts {
   @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**Create.cshtml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using AthlosifyWebArchery.Data;
using AthlosifyWebArchery.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace AthlosifyWebArchery.Pages.Administrators.Users
{
public class CreateModel : UserViewPageModel
{
    private readonly AthlosifyWebArchery.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationUser _applicationUser;

    private string USER_DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "P@$$w0rd";

    public CreateModel(AthlosifyWebArchery.Data.ApplicationDbContext context,
                        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManger;
    }

    public class ApplicationUserViewModel<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Suburb { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string SelectedRoleId { get; set; }
        public string SelectedClubID { get; set; }

        public string SelectedHostID { get; set; }
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        PopulateRolesDropDownList(_context);

        PopulateClubsDropDownList(_context);
        PopulateHostsDropDownList(_context);


        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public ApplicationUserViewModel<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUserVM { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    { 
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Page();

        //_context.User.Add(User);

        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            FirstName = ApplicationUserVM.FirstName,
            LastName = ApplicationUserVM.LastName,
            Address = ApplicationUserVM.Address,
            State = ApplicationUserVM.State,
            Postcode = ApplicationUserVM.Postcode,
            Country = ApplicationUserVM.Country,
            UserName = ApplicationUserVM.UserName,
            Email = ApplicationUserVM.UserName
        };

        var role = _context.Roles.Where(w => w.Id == ApplicationUserVM.SelectedRoleId).FirstOrDefault();

        IEnumerable<string> selectedRoles = new List<string>() { role.Name };

        var adminresult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, USER_DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

        if (adminresult.Succeeded)
        {
            if (selectedRoles != null)
            {

                var result = await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, selectedRoles);
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return Page();
                }
            }
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

}

**UserViewPageModel.cshtml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AthlosifyWebArchery.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace AthlosifyWebArchery.Pages.Administrators.Users
{
    public class UserViewPageModel : PageModel
    {

        public SelectList ClubNameSL { get; set; }

        public SelectList HostNameSL { get; set; }

        public SelectList RoleNameSL { get; set; }

        public void PopulateRolesDropDownList(ApplicationDbContext _context,
            object selectedRole = null)
        {
            var rolesQuery = from d in _context.Roles
                             orderby d.Name // Sort by name.
                             select d;

            RoleNameSL = new SelectList(rolesQuery,
                        "Id", "Name", selectedRole);
        }

        public void PopulateClubsDropDownList(ApplicationDbContext _context,
           object selectedClub = null)
        {
            var clubsQuery = from d in _context.Club
                             orderby d.Name // Sort by name.
                             select d;

            ClubNameSL = new SelectList(clubsQuery,
                        "ClubID", "Name", selectedClub);
        }

        public void PopulateHostsDropDownList(ApplicationDbContext _context,
           object selectedHost = null)
        {
            var hostsQuery = from d in _context.Host
                             orderby d.Name // Sort by name.
                             select d;

            HostNameSL = new SelectList(hostsQuery,
                        "HostID", "Name", selectedHost);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use onchange event dropdownlist for this.

Comment: How do I do this then?

Comment: If you want, I can post a sample, my friend :))

Comment: If you could, that will be good. As most of the sample is for MVC stuff which is different with Razor Pages approach

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response, my friend. The first, you need to hide Clubs and Host  selectlist. And then, show and hide Clubs and Hosts selectlist in onchange event of Roles selectlist. Here is a sample. Hope to help and Happy new year :))

```
<h2>Create</h2>
<h4>User</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.UserName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Role:
                <select asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedRoleId"  class="form-control"
                        asp-items="@Model.RoleNameSL">
                    <option value="">-- Select Role --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedRoleId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="divClub" style="display: none;" >
                Club:
                <select asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedClubID" class="form-control"
                        asp-items="@Model.ClubNameSL">
                    <option value="">-- Select Club --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedClubID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="divHost" style="display: none;">
                Host:
                <select asp-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedHostID" class="form-control"
                        asp-items="@Model.HostNameSL">
                    <option value="">-- Select Host --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ApplicationUserVM.SelectedHostID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
    {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#ApplicationUserVM_SelectedRoleId').on('change', function () {
                let role = $(this).find(":selected").text();
                if (role === 'Club Admin') {
                    $('#divClub').show();
                    $('#divHost').hide();
                } else if (role === 'Host Admin') {
                    $('#divHost').show();
                    $('#divClub').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#divClub').hide();
                    $('#divHost').hide();
                }                                   
            });            
        });
    </script>
}
```